# Unexpected output with node-red-contrib-composer nodes in Composer v0.9.x

Tags: node-red, hyperledger-composer

With the introduction of composer v0.9.0, I noticed very strange behavior with node-red-contrib-composer in node-red. When using the Hyperledger-composer-in node to listen to events from composer, the output now returns excessive junk information along with the information included in the event. Additionally, assets that are referenced/included in the event have some of their properties changed, for example the $class property is changed to $namespace and $type. I am using the basic sample network from the hyperledger github along with this node-red flow: https://pastebin.com/k4Chgs66

```
[
{
    "id": "6541ffea.a8bec8",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "Sample Network",
    "disabled": false,
    "info": ""
}, 
...
```

and here is a sample of the output I am getting from the msg object in my console: https://pastebin.com/5EkNe00h

```
 ValidatedResource { 
 '$modelManager': 
  ModelManager {
  modelFiles: 
  { 'org.hyperledger.composer.system': 
     ModelFile {
       modelManager: [Circular],
       declarations: 
 ...
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? The event notification is working as normal in Composer playground, any reason the node-red output would be different? Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of the node-red-contrib-composer nodes do you have? Looking at the output i think you might have an earlier version which didn't turn the resource into json before sending the output. Can you try updating the nodes and see if you still get the same problem?

Comment: I have 0.0.1, but looking at the manage palette > install menu in node red it looks to me like the only version available to install is 0.0.1 from 1 month ago. Is there an alternate way to install a newer version?

Comment: I can provide the package.json from my .node-red/node_modules/node-red-contrib-composer if that helps

Comment: If you go to `~/.node-red` and do `npm uninstall node-red-contrib-composer` then do `npm install node-red-contrib-composer` hopefully that will work. You will know you have the latest version if you can delete an asset from the `hyperledger-composer output node` (there should be an extra delete option in the drop down)

Comment: Hey that worked! Everything is back to normal with node-red and the delete option is now present. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears there are two Node-Red composer packages in NPM which might of led to some confusion: node-red-contrib-composer and node-red-contrib-hyperledger-composer. I have the later installed. I did uninstall and instead installed node-red-contrib-composer and did not see the Delete option for the Out node

Comment: I deinstalled node-red, delete the .node-red directory, installed node-red and then installed node-red-contrib-composer and it fixed the issue. I verified under the .node-red directory that the node-red-contrib-composer JavaScript had the new Delete option.